# c# Datacolumn in datatable set decimal place

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I have a DataColumn in a DataTable created like this:

```
        DataTable oDt = new DataTable("mytable");
        oDt .Columns.Add("price", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
```

When I enter a value

```
        DataRow oRow = oDt .NewRow();
        oRow["price"] = 1;
        oDt.Rows.Add(oRow);
```

I only see 1 and not 1.00 as I would like, being a decimal column.
Where am I wrong? How can I automatically see two decimal places?
To see the data I use a DataGridView

Comment: DataTable and DataRow are data classes, not UI classes, what are you using to display the data?

Comment: To see the data I use a DataGridView, I have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
int priceIndex = 1; // Index of the price column
dataGridView.Columns[priceIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##"
```

If you don't have the price column's index then you can do it directly using the column name:

```
dataGridView.Columns["price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##"
```